# perl csv data embedded in script

Tags: perl, csv

I have a perl script which I using for file generation.  I would like to embed a lookup table and read into a hash or array.

Example:

```
__DATA__
a,0,0x0
p,0,0x8
s,0,0x6
pm,0,0x1fc0
pm,1,0x1f80
pm,2,0x1f00
```

I am already using Text::CSV for reading a CSV file.  How do I read the data into a hash?  I can add a header row if it make it easier.

Comment: What's the index/id column here? This would be mandatory to read this into a hash. Otherwise, maybe you mean an array of hashes?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emakamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm#getline_hr):

> **getline_hr**
>
> The getline_hr () and column_names () methods work together to allow
> you to have rows returned as hashrefs. You must call column_names ()
> first to declare your column names.

```
$csv->column_names (qw( code name price description ));
$hr = $csv->getline_hr ($io);
print "Price for $hr->{name} is $hr->{price} EUR\n";
```

> getline_hr () will croak if called before column_names ().
>
> **getline_hr_all**

```
$arrayref = $csv->getline_hr_all ($io);
$arrayref = $csv->getline_hr_all ($io, $offset);
$arrayref = $csv->getline_hr_all ($io, $offset, $length);
```

> This will return a reference to a list of getline_hr ($io) results. In
> this call, keep_meta_info is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The special file handle `DATA` points to your script right after the `__DATA__` line. If you need to use it as a parameter of a subroutine or method, use the GLOB sigil:

```
subroutine(*DATA);
```